# Subview of Scrollview doesn't register touch events

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, subview

I'm struggling with this problem, and although there are quite some threads on this issue I've not figured it out yet.

I want to load a button into a subview of a scrollview. If I test this subview alone, the button works fine. Also, when I add the button to the scrollview directly, it works fine. But the two combined I don't get any touch event on the button.

My view hierarchy:

```
UIScrollView
  UIView
    UIButton (A)
  UIButton (B)
```

So button B works fine, A doesn't.

I've tried messing around with the attributes like Cancellable Content Touches, but so far no luck. I'm loading the subview from the storyboard with:

```
ViewVC *viewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewVC"];
```

From the posts I've read, this should just work, so either I'm missing something vital, or I've messed up some attributes along the way. Should I use a delegate to pass the events, or  should this be done automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Give your views some colours, and check if one of them is obscuring the other preventing it from being touched. Maybe you UIView is overlapping your UIButton(B), preventing it from being touched.

Comment: That's not it, I've loaded a ViewController with working buttons into the scrollview and the buttons stopped working. It must be the combination of the scrollview and the subview that gives this error, because each works on it's own.

Comment: Well I can guarantee that you can have the hierarchy that you have, and the UIButton's are clickable. If I were you, get lots of NSLogs and breakpoints in there to step through the code and see what is happening to your clicks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sure you're adding it?

Make sure you're calling `addSubview:` on your `UIScrollView` with your subview as the parameter?

Comment: [scrollView addSubview:viewVC.view];

Comment: The problem shouldn't be with the views then, there is another problem at work.

Comment: Finally figured it out: forgot to add an underscore before a variable. Doh... Thanx for the help.